# Changing text color

Tags: css, wordpress

I have managed to change the color of other text in my woocommerce shop by using the simple custom CSS plugin for WordPress.  But there is 1 text section that will not change.  When you go into the shop and click on SkinCare and soaps and click the cupcake soap it says "6 in stock" which is yellow.  I want to change it to black.  The site is http://84f.6c5.myftpupload.com/  and my CSS for it is

```
.woocommerce .stock in-stock   {
  color: #000000;
}
```

This has got my stumped as the others changed but not this one.
Thanks Linda

Answer (score 1):

You need to apply the two classes simultaneously:

```
.woocommerce .stock.in-stock   {
  color: #000000;
}
```

This selected means apply the properties to an element that  has both `.stock` and `.instock` as classes.

The CSS will work regardless of the order that the two classes are applied.

**Applying the style in WordPress**

The style you want to modify is the following:

```
.woocommerce div.product .stock {
    color: #1E1313;
}
```

which is located in the woocommerce.css file.  You need to find  this file, modify the current CSS rule or add the one I suggested, and then you need to upload the edited woocommerce.css file onto you hosting server.  I checked your website and the style I suggested has not been added to your site.

Comment: I checked your website and the new CSS rule is not present, which means that you did not upload the changes to your web hosting server.

Answer (score 1):

Your CSS is wrong. `in-stock` is a class but you're identifying it as tag.
Also, `in-stock` is not defined within `stock`.
The correct implementation would be

```
.woocommerce .stock.in-stock   {
  color: #000000;
}
```

Comment: I copied and pasted this and it didn't work.  This is what I don't understand the others worked fine just not this one